# Visual C++ doesn't see operator<< overload

Tags: visual-c++, qt4, operator-overloading, compiler-errors

I have a vector class that I want to be able to input/output from a QTextStream object. The forward declaration of my vector class is:

```
namespace util {
  template <size_t dim, typename T>
  class Vector;
}
```

I define the `operator<<` as:

```
namespace util {
template <size_t dim, typename T>
QTextStream& operator<<(QTextStream& out, const util::Vector<dim,T>& vec)
{
   ...
}

template <size_t dim, typename T>
QTextStream& operator>>(QTextStream& in,util::Vector<dim,T>& vec)
{
   ..
}
}
```

However, if I ty to use these operators, Visual C++ returns this error:

```
error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'QTextStream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

A few things I tried:

- Originaly, the methods were defined as friends of the template, and it is working fine this way with g++.
- The methods have been moved outside the namespace util
- I changed the definition of the templates to fit what I found on various Visual C++ websites.

The original friend declaration is:

```
friend QTextStream& operator>>(QTextStream& ss, Vector& in) { ... }
```

The "Visual C++ adapted" version is:

```
friend QTextStream& operator>> <dim,T>(QTextStream& ss, Vector<dim,T>& in);
```

with the function pre-declared before the class and implemented after. I checked the file is correctly included using:

```
#pragma message ("Including vector header")
```

And everything seems fine. Doesn anyone has any idea what might be wrong?

**Note:** the definition of the operator doesn't even appears in the list of operator<< found.

Comment: Please provide the use case of when you are trying to use the operator

Comment: While you're at it, please provide a full, compileable (or not) code example.

Comment: Sadly, trying to reduce the size of the program resolve the problem. It seems to be a weird thing :(

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and I think I figured out what was going on. For some reason, MSVC sometimes mistakes std::endl, for the endl defined in QTextStream (of course if you are "using namespace std" anywhere, this behavior is appropriate).

Also, I think MSVC sometimes gets confused with std::strings (maybe if they are const or addresses or something like that) with QTextStream.

MSVC tends to be very particular about the const/& variants of overloads, especially in cases where there may be some ambiguity. I have seen this before with non-QT code with some overloaded functions.

Of course, the error messages are just confusing so, it might be that my analysis is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without seeing the actual instantiation site, but so far what I noticed is that the error says that there is no suitable operator for QTextStream, and your implementations use QTextStream&. This might be because you are trying to use the operator on an R-Value, these can be converted to const &, but not only &.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to make the overload that took a const Vector actually const.

Comment: Free functions (i.e. non-member functions), such as these operators, cannot be `const`.